# Find pattern in grid

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to build a program in python that finds a given pattern inside a matrix and counts how many times this pattern appear.

```
    pattern = [[1,0,1],
              [0,0,0],
              [1,0,1]]

    grid = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
    def find_pattern(grid,pattern):
        for x in range(len(grid)):
            for y in range (len(grid[0])):
                x0 = (x//3)*3
                y0 = (y//3)*3

                for i in range(len(pattern)):
                    for j in range(len(pattern[0])):
                        if grid[x0 + i][y0 + j] != patter[i][j]:
                            return False

return True
```

Comment: If grid is a matrix NxM, and pattern a matrix AxA, the idea is to iterate over the rows (as you did), but until N - A, then iterate the columns until M - A and check if each row of the pattern equals a slice of grid (`pattern[0]==grid[i][j:j+3]` for example)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
def find_pattern(grid, pattern):
    count = 0
    for x in range(len(grid[0])-len(pattern[0])+1):
        for y in range(len(grid)-len(pattern)+1):
            local = grid[y:y+len(pattern)]
            local = [e[x:x+len(pattern[0])] for e in local]
            if local == pattern:
                count += 1
    return count
```

Basically it loops through all the sections of `grid` that's as big as `pattern`, and then adds one to `count` for every section that's the same as `pattern`.

Example:

```
pattern = [[0,1],
           [1,0]]
grid = [[1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,1,0,1,0]]

print(find_pattern(grid, pattern))
```

outputs `2`